# How can i use a JTABLE to insert data into a database

Tags: java, sql, swing, netbeans

I am making an application for inserting examination marks into a database. I have managed to use a JTable to display data from the database but now i want to use the same JTable to insert data to the database. how i do that?I will appreciate any assistance given

Comment: do you mean, edit an existing value in the JTable and then update the value  in the database, or taking all the elements from a table and then add them all to the database?

Comment: taking all elements then adding to the database

Comment: what are you using to fill the JTable? could you show an example of your code in the answer ?

Comment: i am using a select sql to query the table in the database then displaying the resultset in the JTable.

Comment: How are you changing the TableModel from you JTable? what structure are you using, if you are using an ArrayList to fill your Jtable you could use the same structure in order to edit your elements, just create a class that implement a TableModelListener, and override the tableChanged method in order to make the update

Comment: String sql="select * from exam";
st=con.prepareStatement(sql);
rs=st.executeQuery();
tbl_report.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(this.rs));

Comment: the DbUtils comes from an external library called Rs2xml

Answer (score 0):

You could:

1) Allow the user to select a row they want to edit.

2) Allow the user to click a button that opens a new window with textfields that are populated with the data from the selected row.

3) Add a "save" button to this newly opened window which, when clicked, queries the database and "updates" where xyz = row that has been selected.

Answer (score 0):

How are you changing the `TableModel` from you `JTable`? what structure are you using, if you are using an `ArrayList` to fill your Jtable you could use the same structure in order to edit your elements, just create a class that implement a `TableModelListener`, and override the `tableChanged` method in order to make the update

**Edit:** ok so you have to get the model from your JTable,

`tbl_report.getModel().getValueAt(row, column);` and this will give you the value from a specific cell, since you want all the JTable Values you could make this using a for (indeed two for's) something like this:

```
 ArrayList<Object> value= new  ArrayList<Object> ();
    for (int column = 0; column < resumenTable.getColumnCount(); column++) {
        for (int row = 0; row < resumenTable.getRowCount(); row++) {
         value.add(resumenTable.getModel().getValueAt(row, column));
        }
    }
```

You will have to cast the `ArrayList` elements in order to construct your query